# Investment decision help: How does Bill Ackman invest his own money?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, hedge-funds

As we all know that Warren Buffet invest had almost all of his wealth in Berkshire stocks, I am doing some research around Pershing Square Holding https://pershingsquareholdings.com, When looking at financial reports https://pershingsquareholdings.com/company-reports/financial-statements/, management only owns around 3% of total public shares, which makes me wonder how does Bill Ackman invest his own money?

His personal wealth is claimed to be at 2 billion according to Wikipedia and he has made this great fortune through management fee/performance fee in the past 2 decades. I couldn't find anything useful information online though.

Comment: Buffett also has a large personal portfolio.

Comment: Could you mention how your question is related to personal finance? Are you trying to copy Ackman's personal portfolio?

Comment: I don't understand if his interest is aligned with the interest of his fund.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no way to know.

It's almost certainly in an index fund, such as Vanguard. Passive investment is the most common.

There is also probably several thousand in various checking accounts to meet daily expenses.